# IronRuby, IronPython, or Something Else?

Tags: .net-3.5, ironpython, ironruby

I am looking to build a set of dynamic scripts, stored in a table, that will act as business rules against my EF model.  In the past, I was inclined to use IronRuby or IronPython when thinking about my options.  Much to my dismay, I just read that both are dead! (http://www.ironshay.com/post/IronRuby-and-IronPython-are-Officially-Handed-Over-to-the-Community-IronRuby-Tools-for-VS-is-Out-and-More!.aspx)  What scripting language, compatible and fast with .NET, should I use now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe either IronRuby *or* IronPython is dead, actually... they've recently changed ownership effectively, but they're [still being worked on](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2010/Oct-22.html).

Anyway, you might also want to look at [Boo](http://boo.codehaus.org/).

Comment: Please see my update with the link to who is saying it's dead.  Sounds like as far as M$ goes, they handed the reigns off to the community.

Comment: @Benny: "Handed off to the community" != "dead" IMO. Indeed, the very blog post that you linked to is clearly of the opinion that MS handing them over to the community will be *good* for those projects. Or are you only willing to develop against products from Microsoft?

Answer (score 0):

You still can use C# for this.  You can use Expression Trees to build.  Yes it is not very intuitive, but it allows you to build dynamically expression and execute it.  I just recently used Expression Trees to execute business rules stored in database and it works.